# Business catalyst liquid

Tags: liquid, business-catalyst

Hello Im new to liquid in **business catalyst**. How can I make the option value become a condition in `{% if -%}`

```
{% assign show_cars = "cars" -%}
{% assign show_vans = "vans" -%}

<select class="sample">
 <option value="{{show_cars}}">Show all cars</option>
 <option value="{{show_vans}}">Show all vans</option>
</select>

      <div class="enquiry-car-box">
        <!-- ENQUIRY-CAR-BOX START-->
          {% if show_cars == 'cars' -%}
          {module_webapps template="/sample/sample1.tpl" id="sample" filter="classified" collection="sample1"}
          {% elseif show_vans == 'vans' -%}
          {module_webapps template="/sample/sample2.tpl" id="sample" filter="classified" collection="sample2"}
          {% endif -%}
        <!--ENQUIRY-CAR-BOX END -->
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, not directly.

That code ran before the user ever saw the page; it'll never know which option the user just selected.

To show changes as the user interacts with the page, you'll need to use some JavaScript.

Comment: ahh I see, thanks I thought their is a way liquid can know that.

Comment: just like this in jQuery `$('.sample').val()`